# Replace data in a data-frame with data from another data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data-frames where `df1` looks like:

```
id  Status Colour 
 1      On   Blue
19      On    Red
 4      On  Green
56      On   Blue
```

`df2` looks like

```
id   Status
19      Off
 4     Even
```

I am trying to replace the `Status` in `df1` with the `Status` in `df2` if the `id` is present in both data-frames so my resulting data-frame looks like:

```
id  Status  Colour 
 1      On    Blue
19     Off     Red
 4    Even   Green
56      On    Blue
```

I can identify the field in `df1` that I want to change using:

```
df1.loc[df1['id'].isin(df2['id']), 'Status'] = referenced date
```

But I can't see how to identify the field in `df2` to pass to `df1` (the part to the right of the above equals sign)

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried a merge?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace non matched missing values by `fillna`:

```
df1['Status'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['Status']).fillna(df1['Status'])
print (df1)
   id Status Colour
0   1     On   Blue
1  19    Off    Red
2   4   Even  Green
3  56     On   Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
result = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
result['status'] = result['status_y'].fillna(result['status_x'])
result.drop(['status_x','status_y'],axis=1,inplace=True)


   color  id status
0   blue   1     on
1    red  19    off
2  green   4   even
3   blue  56     on
```